# How do you get Windows user domain/username with C# Razor on IIS 10?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, razor, windows-authentication

Trying to build a web app that will utilize single-sign-on using Windows authentication with Active Directory. I'm having trouble getting the logged in Windows user domain and username. Things I have tried:

- `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

  Returns `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`
- `System.Environment.UserName`

  Returns `DefaultAppPool`
- `Page.User.Identity.Name`

  Results in a compilation error

  Anonymous Authentication is disabled

  ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled

  Windows Authentication is enabled

  Web.config

  > ```
  > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  > <configuration>
  >   <appSettings>
  >     <add key="EnableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
  >   </appSettings>
  >   <system.web>
  >     <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.1">
  >       <assemblies>
  >         <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
  >         <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  >       </assemblies>
  >     </compilation>
  >     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  >     <authentication mode="Windows" />
  >     <authorization>
  >       <deny users="?" />
  >     </authorization>
  >     <identity impersonate="true" />
  >   </system.web>
  >   <runtime>
  >     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  >       <dependentAssembly>
  >         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  >         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  >       </dependentAssembly>
  >       <dependentAssembly>
  >         <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  >         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  >       </dependentAssembly>
  >       <dependentAssembly>
  >         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  >         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  >       </dependentAssembly>
  >       <dependentAssembly>
  >         <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
  >         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  >       </dependentAssembly>
  >     </assemblyBinding>
  >   </runtime>
  >   <system.webServer>
  >     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  >     </modules>
  >     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  >     <handlers>
  >       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  >       <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  >       <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  >       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  >     </handlers>
  >   </system.webServer>
  > </configuration>
  > ```

Comment: Have you tried checking the User under the current request when in the view. `@User.Identity`

Comment: BTW, you don't need impersonation enabled in order to get Windows identity. It matters only when you accessing another server and want to "delegate" credentials of user that accessed your server.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to adjust, depending on on the **context** that you are trying to access the current user

e.g. from a `Controller` you can do the following:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

make sure that you are using:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Comment: The web app does not use a MVC framework. It is strictly C#/Razor.

Comment: So how is your app handling the requests? Do you use ASP.NET Core, or it is ASP.Net app?

Comment: It's an ASP.net app. Haven't thought about requests yet. I just started learning ASP.net.

Comment: So how do you render the page? Can you provide the example of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var windowsIdentity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
```

Comment: I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: OK, just to ensure, add System.Web to HttpContext. I updated the answer.

Comment: Adding `System.Web` doesn't change anything.